# Program to find the element in an array

Tags: java, beginner, array, search

I'd like this code to be improved.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayElementFind {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] arr= { "A","B","C","D"};

        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the char to search");
        String a=in.nextLine();

        //int len=arr.length;

        boolean check=loopcheck(arr,a);

        if(check){
            System.out.println("Element is present");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Element is not present");
        }


    }

    private static boolean loopcheck(String[] arr, String a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        for(String s:arr){
            if(s.equals(a)){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Since you're not using the [`try`-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement with `Scanner`, you must close it at the end of `main()` to avoid leaking resources:

  ```
  in.close();
  ```
- You should consider converting `a` to uppercase, in case the input is in lowercase.

  I would also rename `a` to something like `guess`.  The name `a` says nothing about this variable, and it's generally discouraged to use single-letter variable names.

  ```
  String guess = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
  ```

  The renaming also applies to `arr`.  You could name it something like `elemsToCheck`.

Answer (score 6):

Minor nitpick that wasn't touched on: The assignments could use a little breathing space around the `=` for better readability. There's also inconsistent spacing between the brackets.

```
    String[] arr= { "A","B","C","D"};
```

Becomes

```
    String[] arr = {"A","B","C","D"};
```

And

```
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
```

Becomes

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Etc.

The `check` Boolean is unneeded. If you were calling `loopcheck()` more than once, I would say to leave it, but you're not. So don't.

```
    if(loopcheck(arr,a)){
        System.out.println("Element is present");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Element is not present");
    }
```

You should also remove these comments. You've filled in the code already. They're just noise, not just in the code, but in your IDE's ToDo list as well.

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: So do I! You're welcome and welcome to Code Review.